# Upper bounding this integral.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, upper-lower-bounds

Would appreciate any help in finding a good **closed form** upper bound on this integral not in terms of the exponential integral $Ei(x)$:

$$ I = \int_{t=0}^x \frac{e^t-1}{t}dt$$

So far I have tried using the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality to get something of the form $\frac{e^x-1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: Are you interested in approximations for $x\to 0^+$ or $x\gg 1$?

Comment: Both are welcome. I am actually looking for a universal upper bound. But if the best means to do that is by piecewise analysis, then so be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x$ is close to zero the Maclaurin series says pretty much everything:
$$ g(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{e^t-1}{t}\,dt = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n\cdot n!} \tag{1} $$
and also proves that the LHS is an entire function. We may notice that de l'Hopital rule implies
$$ \lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{g(x)}{\frac{e^x-1}{x}} = 1 \tag{2}$$
and $\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{(n+1)\cdot n!}$ is actually a decent *lower* bound for $g(x)$. In order to turn it into an *upper bound*, we may notice that for any $n\geq 2$ we have $\frac{1}{n}\leq \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)}$. This leads to
$$ g(x)\leq \frac{6(x+2)e^x-\left(12+18 x+12 x^2-x^3\right)}{6x^2}\tag{3} $$
which is horrible but accurate.

Comment: Nice observations! The lower bound should be $$\frac{e^x-1}x - 1.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_0^x\dfrac{e^t-1}{t}dt=\int_0^x\int_0^1e^{at}dadt=\int_0^1\int_0^xe^{at}dtda\leq\int_0^1\int_0^xe^{ax}dtda=e^x-1$$

Comment: This is a good approximation when $x$ is small, but an application of l'hopital's rule shows that the limit: $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{I}{(e^x-1)/x}$ is 1. So the bound significantly deviates when $x is large$.

Answer (score 2):

The nice upper bound given by Jack’s answer fits in a whole sequence of ever tighter upper bounds. For any  $n \in \mathbb{N}$ define the polynomial $$e_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}.$$
Repeating partial integration $n$ times shows that
$$\int_0^x\frac{e^t-1}t\mathrm{d}t = \sum_{k=1}^n (k-1)! \frac{e^x-e_k(x)}{x^k}+n! \int_0^x \frac{e^t-e_n(t)}{t^{n+1}}\mathrm{d}t.$$ Now any upper bound for the integral in the right hand side results in an upper bound for the left hand side. Simply using the trapezium rule results in
$$\int_0^x\frac{e^t-1}t\mathrm{d}t \leq \sum_{k=1}^n(k-1)! \frac{e^x-e_k(x)}{x^k} + n!\frac{e^x-e_n(x)}{2x^n} + \frac{x}{2n+2}.$$ The first couple of bounds are then:
$$\tag{$n$=0} \frac{e^x-1}2 + \frac{x}2$$
$$\tag{$n$=1} \frac{3(e^x-(x+1))}{2x} + \frac{x}4$$
$$\tag{$n$=2} \frac{(x+2)e^x - (2x^2+3x+2)}{x^2} + \frac{x}6$$
$$\tag{$n$=3} \frac{6(x^2+x+5)e^x - (14 x^3 + 27 x^2 + 36 x + 30)}{6x^3} + \frac{x}8$$